# Iniciales de un Texto, segunda parte

Tags: python

Me están pidiendo esto:

"Se le proporciona un archivo llamado "books.txt" con títulos de libros, cada uno en una línea separada.
Para codificar los títulos de los libros, debe tomar las primeras letras de cada palabra en el título y combinarlas.
Por ejemplo, para el título del libro "Juego de tronos", la versión codificada debería ser "GoT".

Complete el programa para leer el título del libro desde el archivo y generar las versiones codificadas, cada una en una nueva línea."

Este es mi código:

````
```file = open('D:/Users/eruizl01/Desktop/prueba.txt', 'r+')
   lista = file.readlines()
      for i in lista:
      words = i.split()
      clave = ''.join(i[0] for i in i.split())
      clave2 = file.write('\n' + clave)
   file.close()```
````

Este es el resultado del código:

> ï»¿hola mundo
> python es chevere
> saludos a todos
> ïm
> pec
> sat

Sin embargo, al ser evaluado no me lo valida. La pregunta es, ¿la verdad ya no se qué estoy haciendo mal?, ¿En donde está el error?

Comment: Y tu output esperado es solamente los últimos 3?

Comment: Yo no te puedo decir si esta bien o mal el resultado, pues no se conoce la entrada

Comment: La entrada son los primeros tres textos que aparecen en la respuesta

Comment: En ese caso la salida es correcta, que esperas?

Comment: En efecto alfa, lo que yo pienso que debería ser la salida esperada son los tres últimos

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que no sé que esperan ellos Christian. Hice la corrida en el archivo de prueba que ellos tienen y para ellos no es correcto.

Comment: Lo peor es que no hay manera de hacer feedback con ellos al respecto.

Comment: Si no tienes una salida esperado o una forma de saber el resultado correcto entonces cualquier respuesta que te den sería adivinando lo que las haría inválidas

Comment: Desafortunadamente voy a ciegas, ya que para poder ver el resultado esperado debo pagar una premium y pues, no cuento con eso.

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero tanto tu como nosotros vamos a ciegas y en mi caso es imposible darte una respuesta concreta

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que el código no está tan lejos de lo descrito en el problema, te propongo una una ayuda, donde el primer `with` abre el archivo `books.txt` como solo lectura y el segundo `with` crea un `prueba.txt` en blanco.

Dentro del `for` se procesa cada línea y el resultado es escrito en el segundo archivo, `prueba.txt`.

```
with open('books.txt') as f1:
    with open('prueba.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for line in f1:
            first_letters = [x[0] for x in line.split(' ')]
            f2.write(''.join(first_letters) + '\n')
```

Comment: Ok, voy a intentar con este a ver como me va